# Maven pom.xml - build modules + self build

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, build-process

I have the next project structure:

```
app
module1
module2
...
moduleN
parent-pom
```

Project `app` contains only properties files and *JasperReports*'s reports templates. Pom.xml of app:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../parent-pom</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>${app-version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>../module1</module>
    <module>../module2</module>
    ...
    <module>../moduleN</module>
</modules>
```

I want to add ***jasperreports-maven-plugin*** for project app. I've tried next code (before `<modules>` section), but it doesn't work (self build wasn't called):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/config/templates</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/config/templates</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is it possible to add self build to pom with modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app project packaging is set to pom - so it can't have any other artifacts.  You will need to move the jasper reports to one of the other modules or a separate module.